# Simple mapreduce pairwise comparison

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning mapreduce. I want to implement a naive nearest neighbor search-- complexity O(n^2). To do this, I expect to use nested loops to iterate over the input items. The inner loop compares two items and writes out the distance between them.

I think what I need to do is pass all the items in the input split into the mapper. I do not know how to do this. If I use a TextInputFormat, what will the the context's getCurrentValue() method return? All lines in all input files, or something else?

How about NLineFormat? Will the split size be set to N?

Advice is welcome. I'm not ready to dive into academic papers on the subject.

**...**

Thanks for the comments. Here are my updates:

- Each input item is a feature vector of nominal values. The distance between two items is just the number of corresponding fields with different values.
- The output is going to be something simple: item#1_ID, item#2_ID, distance
- I'm just testing a sample of 500 items so it runs quickly. I would not use this approach on a large real-life data set. There a slide deck out there an approximate nearest-neighbor matching in mapreduce. If I take this project further, I'll probably follow that approach.

Comment: Could you please specify the input? e.g. an example line. Furthermore the problem of n^2 algorithms in MR is that you need every data point in every mapper. Naive algorithms are in general not advisable because you easily lose the scaleability. If your structure is not a graph with specific neighbors and an edge weight it will become complicated.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the mapper. If you want to read the files directly of HDFS, then go for it. This is going to be incredibly slow in MapReduce.